# Statistical attacks on a list of MD5/SHA-1 hashes?

Tags: cryptanalysis, sha-1, attack, md5

I have a list of MD5 and SHA-1 hashes where the input string is of the form

```
secret1000
secret1001
…
```

all the way up to

```
secret2000
```

Are there any attacks, analytical techniques that can give me any insights on the input strings?

Comment: None are known, and it would be a significant result, as you really do see hashes like that in practice...

Comment: Why, you already know the input strings, right ;) Nah, Poncho is correct. MD5 and SHA-1 have been broken for collision, but then the input should still be formatted in a specific way. More importantly for your question: there is still no chance of finding the input (without "guessing" it correctly); they are still one-way-functions.

Comment: More precisely, nothing is known better than trying various values of secret, from most likely to least, until getting a hit. If secret is 6 chars, that's easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments sum it up perfectly…

> [Poncho’s comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/statistical-attacks-on-a-list-of-md5-sha-1-hashes#comment127899_58210):
>     None are known, and it would be a significant result, as you really do see hashes like that in practice...

and

> [Maarten Bodewes’s comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/58210/statistical-attacks-on-a-list-of-md5-sha-1-hashes#comment127904_58210):
>     MD5 and SHA-1 have been broken for collision, but then the input should still be formatted in a specific way. More importantly for your question: there is still no chance of finding the input (without "guessing" it correctly); they are still one-way-functions.